# Forward a file upload to other server

Tags: http, go, curl, facebook-graph-api, file-upload

I'm trying to upload local video via Facebook Graph API.

This is official Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/attachment-upload-api/

```
  -F 'message={"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{"is_reusable":true}}}' \
  -F 'filedata=@/tmp/shirt.png;type=image/png' \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/me/message_attachments?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

And this is my Golang code:

```golang
func uploadVideoStream(c *Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(MAXIMUM_PLUGIN_FILE_SIZE); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    m := r.MultipartForm

    fileArray, ok := m.File["files"]
    if !ok {
        c.Err = model.NewAppError("uploadPlugin", "api.plugin.upload.no_file.app_error", nil, "", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    if len(fileArray) <= 0 {
        c.Err = model.NewAppError("uploadPlugin", "api.plugin.upload.array.app_error", nil, "", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    file, err := fileArray[0].Open()

    if err != nil {
        c.Err = model.NewAppError("uploadPlugin", "api.plugin.upload.file.app_error", nil, "", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // build a form body
    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

    _message := uploadVideoData{
        Message: uploadVideoDataMessage{
            Attachment: uploadVideoDataMessageAttachment{
                Type: "video",
                Payload: uploadVideoDataMessageAttachmentPayload{
                    IsReusable: true,
                },
            },
        },
    }

    // add form fields
    writer.WriteField("message", _message.Message.ToJson())

    // add a form file to the body
    fileWriter, err := writer.CreateFormFile("filedata", fileArray[0].Filename)
    if err != nil {
        c.Err = model.NewAppError("upload_video", "upload_video.error", nil, "", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    // copy the file into the fileWriter
    _, err = io.Copy(fileWriter, file)
    if err != nil {
        c.Err = model.NewAppError("upload_video", "upload_video.error", nil, "", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    // Close the body writer
    writer.Close()

    reqUrl := "https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me/message_attachments"
    token := "EAAUxUcj3C64BADxxsm70hZCXTMO0eQHmSpV..."
    reqUrl += "?access_token=" + token

    var netTransport = &http.Transport{
        Dial: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout: 120 * time.Second,
        }).Dial,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout:   120 * time.Second,
        ResponseHeaderTimeout: 120 * time.Second, // This will fixed the i/o timeout error
    }

    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout:   time.Second * 120,
        Transport: netTransport,
    }

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", reqUrl, body)

    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+token)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())

    resp, err1 := client.Do(req)

    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Println("error1", err1)
        c.Err = model.NewAppError("EditComment", err1.Error(), nil, "", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    } else {
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        var bodyBytes []byte
        bodyBytes, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        resp.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes))

        if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
            fmt.Println("error2", resp.Body)
            fbErr := facebookgraph.FacebookErrorFromJson(resp.Body)
            c.Err = model.NewAppErrorFromFacebookError("EditComment", fbErr)
            return
        }

        fmt.Println("UPLOAD VIDEO SUCCESS", resp.Body)

        ReturnStatusOK(w)
    }
}
```

And this is some struct for above code:

```golang
type uploadVideoDataMessageAttachmentPayload struct {
    IsReusable bool `json:"is_reusable"`
}

type uploadVideoDataMessageAttachment struct {
    Type    string                                  `json:"type"`
    Payload uploadVideoDataMessageAttachmentPayload `json:"payload"`
}

type uploadVideoDataMessage struct {
    Attachment uploadVideoDataMessageAttachment `json:"attachment"`
}

type uploadVideoData struct {
    Message uploadVideoDataMessage `json:"message"`
}

func (o uploadVideoData) ToJson() string {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(o)
    return string(b)
}

func (o uploadVideoDataMessage) ToJson() string {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(o)
    return string(b)
}
```

Facebook always return failed for above request:

```
(#100) Upload attachment failure.
```

I was trying CURL, and success:

```
curl \
-F 'message={"attachment":{"type":"video", "payload":{"is_reusable":true}}}' \
-F 'filedata=@/home/cong/Downloads/123.mp4;type=video/mp4' \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me/message_attachments?access_token=EAAUxUcj3C64BADxxsm70hZCXTMO0eQHmSp..."
{"attachment_id":"382840319882695"}%
```

Can any one tell me what part i've missed, and how to make my request equivalent to CURL to work?

Thank you very much!

Comment: In my experience golang will not add any extra headers, while curl might. Maybe try running your curl command with `-v` and see if there are any extra headers that might be relevant.

Comment: Did you get any sub error code in upload response?  Subcode in error response may be more relevant.

Comment: @sigkilled: The subcode error is 2018047: "Upload attachment failure. A common way to trigger this error is that the provided media type does not match type of file provided int the URL". This seem to be my problem, but i'm not sure how to set mediatype to match

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sigkilled
Following his suggestion, I've check subcode_error and found out that this error is caused by miss match file type, between filetype i've set in:

```golang
_message := uploadVideoData{
        Message: uploadVideoDataMessage{
            Attachment: uploadVideoDataMessageAttachment{
                Type: "video",
                Payload: uploadVideoDataMessageAttachmentPayload{
                    IsReusable: true,
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

And the filetype that detected by Facebook server. Then I've change "video" to "file" and it success!

Thank you very much, you've teach me not just this problem!